# While Loop for Database look up

Tags: javascript, node.js

We've designed our site so that we can use a blog's slug to get its content, for example `www.mysite.com/blog/blog_1`

'blog_1' being the slug (I know I'm insulting your intelligence).

That slug is determined with this simple method:

```
let slug = blog.title.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-')
```

So something like 'This is my blog title' would be 'this-is-my-blog-title'.

However, we can't have duplicate slugs. Therefore I tried this:

```
let slug = blog.title.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-')
let i

do {
  slug += i
  i++
}
while (await Blog.find({ slug })
```

However, it seems to hang up. Can you even use await inside a while loop? I just want to increment the slug name by one until the database call returns null at which point I can use that slug for the blog.

Any ideas?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use await in do..while loops. For example :

```js
async function test(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(i < 10)
    }, 1000)
  })
}

async function main () {
  let i = 0
  do {
    console.log(i)
    i++
  } while (await test(i))
}

main()
```

You should first correct some minor errors, such as `let i = 0` instead of just `let i`, and there is a missing parenthesis at the end of your code.

If it still does not work, you should probably check your function `Blog.find()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for of` with `await`

```
let counter= [0];
let slug;
for( let i of counter){
  slug+=i; 
  let result = await Blog.find({ slug })
  if(result){
    counter.push(i+=1)
  }
}
```